# Get Route Data in class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5 you can get RouteData from

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

In MVC 6, I want to get the RouteData, I have to access it from:

```
IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
```

But it doesn't have the Route Dictionary Property.

How do I do this in MVC 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be extracted within any [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters), though it probably makes the most sense in a [ResourceFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#resource-filters). All of the various filters' `*Context` objects inherit from the same [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext) which has the `RouteData` property you're looking for. From there, you can copy it on to the `Items` collection on the [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext) (conveniently, also available on the filter's `*Context` object) for use in other code further down the invocation pipeline.

Here is an example that extracts it via the [`ResourceExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.resourceexecutingcontext) in a [ResourceFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#resource-filters).

```
public class ExtractRouteValueResourceFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter {

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next) {
        var value = context.RouteData.Values["key"];

        if (value != null) {
            context.HttpContext.Items["key"] = value;
        }

        await next();
    }

}
```

In any code that runs after your filter, you could now access the route value via the [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor) like so:

```
var routeValue = accessor.HttpContext.Items["key"];
```

Comment: I would recommend adding some extension methods as well to avoid magic strings and runtime casts around the use of this route value, but I digress.

Comment: I still dont have idea how to get it from `httpContextAccessor` :/

Answer (score 4):

I found solution here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3826

```
string parameter = "action" // or controller
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue(parameter);
```

Comment: +1 Nice find! I was unaware that extension method even existed. This data is backed by the `IRoutingFeature` that gets populated via the [`RouterMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.routermiddleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Unless a developer wants to abstract away where the value comes from (route vs. header, etc.), this seems like a preferential solution to what I showed above in a filter.