# Getting list of routes for specific actions from a specific controller having strong typing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, lambda, .net-core

I want to be able to get the routes for specific actions of a controller.

This is signature.

```
string extractRoute<T>(Action<T> action)
{
     doing something 

     return string.Empty;
 }
```

I want to use it like this:

```
string route1 = extractRoute<SomeController>(x => x.GetAll);
string route2 = extractRoute<SomeController>(x => x.Delete);
```

and the results are going to be stored in a collection

Getting this compile error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

SomeController is an API controller

And

GetAll is an Action on that controller.

```
Task<ActionResult<SomeResult>> GetAll(Request requesT) 
{
      throw new System.NotImplemented(); 
}
```

Delete is an Action on that controller.

```
Task<ActionResult<bool>> Delete (int id) 
{
      throw new System.NotImplemented(); 
}
```

Comment: What `GetAll` is?

Comment: I've updated the question. But the idea is that I want to be able to add to a collection multiple Actions of a controller which will have the signatures

Comment: extractRoute<SomeController>(x => x.GetAll);
to
extractRoute<SomeController>(x => x.GetAll());

Comment: @Daniel, that way I'm calling the GetAll, which is not the desired result, I want to be able to process it's metadata

Comment: @Johnny, Not sure I understand, I want to be able to use strong typing on a controller not a request, which I am, the problem is that I want to be able to pass each Action as a delegate which I'm not.

Comment: `Action<T>` is not the same thing as an "action" in the context of a controller. Specifically, it's a delegate type that has no return. You most likely want an `Expression<Func<T>>`. However, that just gets you over this particular hump. Got no idea how you're planning to somehow use this to get a route, because it doesn't really work that way.

Comment: If you're within the request pipeline, you can inject `IActionContextAccessor` and `IUrlHelperFactory` to create a `UrlHelper` instance, or for other scenarios you can use the `LinkGenerator` singleton in ASP.NET Core 2.2+, but it's functionality is pretty limited currently. Other than that, there's no *reliable* way to get a route based on a controller and action.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470425/get-route-data-in-class